# How to check is connection to database opened?

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

I have problem: i don't know how to check does connection to database is established.

I used:

```
Dim sqlConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(SQLconnectionEntry)
'SQLconnectionEntry is specified earlier
sqlConnection.Open()
```

after opening connection, i have to check is it established, but i stuck.

Any suggestions?

Thx.

EDIT:

Also, how to check does connection is NULL?
Thx

EDIT:

I found an answer... simply:

> Dim isOpen As Boolean
>           If (sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
>               isOpen = True
>           Else
>               isOpen = False

And it works for me.

Hope that will help for others.

Comment: Why do you need to check? If Open returns the connection is open.

Comment: I'll answer this. It throws an exception if you try and open an existing connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What about:**

```
if (sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open)Then

//Your Code here

End if
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the state of your connection like so:

```
If sqlConnection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
End If
```

Comment: @Rusmir - It's been a while since I've done vb.net.  It was C# and then I changed the operator from != to <> it should work now.

Comment: Ugh, I'm glad I no longer develop in it.  Anyways you can take what I have and convert to vb.net...its simple.  I just converted it.